# Rails validation and related tables issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There are many students and each student belongs to a program.

I have a controller:

```
def edit
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @programs = Program.all
end
```

Then I have an edit form (simplified):

```
<%= f.label(:program_id, "Program") %>
<%= f.select(:program_id, @programs.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>
```

Finally, I have a model for the student:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program  

    validates :first_name, presence: true
end
```

I can update a student, as long as I input a first name. If I leave first name blank, I get an error `undefined method 'collect' for nil:NilClass`

However, if I change the form just a little bit, everything works. Like so:

```
<%= f.label(:program_id, "Program") %>
<%= f.select(:program_id, Program.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>
```

Notice the `Programs.all` in there. Instead of in the controller.

What gives? I'd really like to define @programs in the controller. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

P.S. If I take the validation rule out of the model, everything works again--so I'm pretty sure the validation is at the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an update method in your controller? My guess is in the update action you have an if statement that says if the save fails, render the edit template again. If you are rendering the edit template from the update method, the view no longer knows about @programs, so you would need to redefine again in the update method, or create a before_action.